# Decoding bytearray in Python3-x

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have been trying to send an image using a socket but a I'm having a big encoding issue. I'm running a server with python-2.7 and a client on python-3.

I think that the problem is in this function:

```
def decode_image(image):
    imageArray = str(bytearray(image))
    nparr = np.fromstring(imageArray, np.uint8)
    nparr.shape = (320, 240, 3)
    nparr = cv2.cvtColor(nparr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    print(nparr)
    return nparr
```

If I run the code with python2.7 interpreter everything works normally, however, with python3 interpreter it doesn't. The error I'm getting is the following:

```
nparr.shape = (320, 240, 3)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 597048 into shape (320,240,3)
```

Which means that instead of 320*240*3 (230400) decoded elements there are 597048. What is the equivalent way to decode a bytearray with python3 to obtain the same results as with python2.7?

`image` is a `bytes` value.

Comment: Drop the `str()` call, it is absolutely not needed in Python 3.

Comment: What is `image` here? A binary value in a `bytes()` object?

Comment: Please show your function that sends the image.

Comment: Side-note: `str(bytearray(image))`, where `image` is a Python `str` object in Python 2, is just an expensive way of creating another `str` object. `str(bytearray(image)) == image` in that case.

Comment: Yes @MartijnPieters , it's a bytes() object.

Comment: @tul1: can you please at least include better information about what type of data is contained in `image`? It obviously has a length of `230400` (otherwise the reshape would fail). How do you get the value now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to decode the data, nor do you need to use a `bytearray()` here at all. Numpy can accept a `bytes` value directly using [`numpy.frombuffer()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html).

The error you see is due to the `str()` call:

```
str(bytearray(image))
```

which returns the *Python representation* of the `bytearray()` object:

```
>>> bytearray(5)
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
>>> str(bytearray(5))
"bytearray(b'\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00')"
```

`str()` returned a string with the same data as what was echoed for the first expression. You are passing the `bytearray(b'` prefix, the literal `\x` characters and digits to numpy. That's 14 bytes of extra data surrounding your data, and the data itself has been ballooned by a large factor as any non-printable character has been split out into ASCII hex digits plus a backslash and `x` character. This is why your data can't be reshaped, your binary data *was* 230400 bytes long, but has been 'reshaped' to a string representation that happens to use 597048 characters, so roughly 2.6 letters per input byte.

If `image` is a `bytes` value or an object implementing the Python buffer interface, *just pass this value directly to `numpy.frombuffer()`*:

```
nparr = np.frombuffer(image, np.uint8)
```

If `image` might be an integer or an iterable of integers in the range (0-255), then just create a `bytes()` object from that value. So the following line will work correctly for whatever type `image` might be:

```
nparr = np.frombuffer(bytes(image), np.uint8)
```

There are other types that `bytearray()` might have accepted and still work, but those won't work in your specific code example.

Answer (score 1):

You should `decode` the `bytearray`;

```
imageArray = bytearray(image).decode()
```

Here's an example (modified from [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html)):

```
>>> np.fromstring(b'1 2'.decode(), dtype=int, sep=' ')
array([1, 2])
```

On the other hand: `str(b'1 2') == "b'1 2'"`.

Comment: You don't even need to decode for `np.fromstring()` to work.

Comment: And this is **image data**, this will almost certainly not be decodable as UTF8. Note that they are not using `sep` in Python 2 *either*, this is a direct map from byte value to numpy array.

Comment: Honestly, this answer *can't work*, so I don't know why it is being upvoted. `image` is a `bytes` value with binary image data. `bytearray(image).decode()` can't ever be decoded as UTF-8 in that case. It certainly doesn't contain ascii numbers separated by spaces.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, if the OP was using `np.fromstring`, I was assuming they knew for sure that the data was containing ASCII numbers with an appropriate separator. Of course, `bytearray`s can contain any sort of bytes that may not be ASCII- or UTF8-decodable, but the usage of `np.fromstring` suggests that in this case, these bytes _should_ be decodable. I agree that having an image encoded in such a way may be strange, but we don't know what `bytearray(image)` looks like anyway...

Comment: In Python 2, `np.fromstring()` was the equivalent of `np.frombuffer()`, essentially. The `str(bytearray(...))` dance was surprising but perhaps understandable if `image` wasn’t a (Python 2) `str` with image data (so an iterable of integers or a single integer or some more exotic form of object that did support the buffer protocol). It could never have been a sequence of ASCII numbers as they never set a separator.

Comment: Perhaps the [numpy v1.3 documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.3.x/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) helps here; since 1.4 the “binary input” variant (with `sep` not set) is instead delegated to `numpy.frombuffer()` (in Python 2 a *Unicode* string would be encoded at that point, Python 3 `str()` is encoded as UTF8, so decoding, then calling fromstring is utterly useless in this scenario).